# Limit JavaScript to only work inside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to execute a script only inside an element? 
For example I have a list of `<div>` elements with two `<span>` inside of each element. I check with JS if any div has a class called "boo" assigned to it. If it does, it should add a class "hide" to the `<span>` with the class "child2", if not, it should add the class "hide" to the other `<span>` with the class "child1".
Here's an example of what I mean.

```
<div> <span class="child1"></span><span class="child2"></span> </div>
<div class="boo"> <span class="child1"></span><span class="child2"></span> </div>
```

If I'd now use a script like the following, it would mess up the whole list,  because it would also add the class "hide" to the other elements. How can I solve this?

```
var check = $("div").hasClass("boo");
                  if (check === true) {
                  $( ".child2" ).addClass("hide");
                  }
                  else {
                    $( ".child1" ).addClass("hide");
                  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because your code is looking at the first `div` only, and all the `.child1` and `.child2` elements.

To fix this amend your selector to select by the presence (or lack of) the `.boo` class:

```js
$('div.boo .child2').addClass('hide');
$('div:not(.boo) .child1').addClass('hide');
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
  No boo
  <span class="child1">
    Child 1
    <span class="child2">Child 2</span> 
  </span>
</div>
<div class="boo">   
  Boo
  <span class="child1">
    Child 1
    <span class="child2">Child 2</span> 
  </span>
</div>
```

Also note that if this is being done *only* for UI reasons then you should not be using JS at all. It can be achieved in CSS alone:

```css
div:not(.boo) .child1,
div.boo .child2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  No boo
  <span class="child1">
    Child 1
    <span class="child2">Child 2</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="boo">
  Boo
  <span class="child1">
    Child 1
    <span class="child2">Child 2</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Finally note that your `span` elements are missing a closing tag. I presume this is just a typo in the question so I corrected it in this example.

Comment: oh thanks, it took me so long testing everything that I lost the easy solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this:

```
let children = document.querySelectorAll('div.boo .child2, div:not(.boo) .child1');

for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
  children[j].classList.add("hide");
}
```

You also miss some closing span tags in your html, I'm assuming is just a typo.

Also, as stated above, if it's just a matter of presentation you can accomplish this with simple css.

Comment: If you're avoiding jQuery then it makes far more sense to use `querySelectorAll('div.boo .child2, div:not(.boo) .child1')` etc and loop through them to add the `hide` class.